# Java code to test current device is having an incoming call running on Appium server

Tags: java, android, appium

I need to detect incoming call while running the test cases .
I am using Appium ,Java.

Comment: SO != free coding service! Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried anything at all ?? Is there any code ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect through Appium, check for the text in id -
`android.widget.TextView com.android.incallui:id/callStateLabel` which should be `Incoming call`. This may change across different phones. Alternatively you can also run `adb` command to check if there is an incoming call: `adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry | grep mCallState` and `mCallState=1`